# Create a for loop that combines vectors into matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a for loop, where each loop returns a vector. At the end of each loop I want to combine combine that vector with the previously generated vectors into a matrix.

For example, let's say the first loop creates [1,2,3] and the second loop creates [4,5,6], the end of the 2nd loop would combine these to create:

```
 [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6]]
```

The 3rd loop creates [7,8,9], now the matrix will be:

```
 [[1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]]
```

I tried np.concetante, but the issue with this is I would have to transform each vector into a [1,3] matrix on each loop or else it combines them into 1 vector. It's also difficult on the first loop when there is nothing to combine the matrix with.

Is there an easier way to essentially "stack" the vectors together at the end of each loop?

Comment: Try vstack or hstack.

Comment: np.vstack maybe?

Comment: If you know in advance how many loops you'll iterate over, it would make sense to preallocate an array of the necesary size and then do `matrix[i] = vector` in the loop.

Comment: Collect them into one list and concatenate, or `stack`, the whole list once.